# Remove Navigation bar from WPF Browser Application

Tags: wpf

How do I remove the Navigation bar from a WPF Browser Application? I'm using an iframe to hold the xbap and when I open the web page with the WPF browser app, it shows the forward/back navigation buttons in the iframe.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per: http://weblogs.asp.net/plip/archive/2007/11/11/building-wpf-applications-with-the-page-navigation-framework-it-s-just-like-asp-net-but-with-state.aspx, it's just a matter of

```
this.ShowsNavigationUI = false;
```

Comment: This is also possible in XAML as <Page ShowsNavigationUI="False"...> </Page>. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 18):

Navigation is also at the Frame level so you may need to disable it there.
This sample is for Frame but the same may apply for iframe.

```
   <Frame Source="PageSearch.xaml" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" />
```